# how to migrate schema specific in typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have a specific connection for postgres:

```
const dbconfig: DataSourceOptions = {
      ...baseConnection,
      schema: tenantSchema,
      migrations: ['./**/*.migration.js'],
    };

let data = new DataSource(dbconfig);
data = await data.initialize();
data.runMigrations()
```

this actually runs all migration,  , the migrations table which are `migrations`, and `typeorm_metadata` are generated into the `tenantSchema`, but all other tables are generated into the public schema.

I need to automate this via api calls, and I can't  really string replace schema prefixes for structural reasons, setting `search_path` on every query requires some sort of shared variable which I'd like to avoid. What options do I have or am I making some mistake or missing something for migration configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Up function that typeorm provides, before the first sql statement, you could put a set local search_path to <your_schema>` dynamically.  i.e:

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    const query = `SET search_path TO ${this.SCHEMA};
             <your query>`;
    await queryRunner.query(query);
  }
```

Comment: I did use the search path route, but maybe you could add more details for the post to be a bit more understandable

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but if you create your migrations with the above config and not with `baseConnection`, your migration should already contain the correct schema. Maybe something is misconfigured, can't tell with all files.

As workaround: Write the schema directly to the entities annotation like e.g.

```
...
@Entity("myEntity", { schema: "my_schema" })
...
```

Comment: yeah, I event print the config before running migrations, and the schema isn't applied, I can't do the above as you suggest since the schema has to be dynamic for api calls

Comment: "before running migrations"? What is the exact use case here? You need to define the schema before creating(!) the migrations. Migrations are basically just `queryBuilder.query` where your schema is prefixed.  If you created them with the wrong schema then it is already too late without manual editing or string replacement etc.

Comment: I print the object `dbconfig` above. :-D. The schemas are created by the admin and I just run the above config as shown literally. As an api user, the admin would just request to setup a specific tenant, given the payload should specify the schema, everything else should automate

Comment: all I can think of is in the queryRunner that typeorm provides: `public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void>` , it fetches a different instance of the connection from the connection pool. Yet I don't know how to fetch the instance of the connection specified during initiating the migration, or confirm my theory.

Comment: How your migrations exactly look like? Like already said: Normally generated migrations do things like this: ``await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "public"."some_table" ADD "a_new_column" double precision`);``. Where "public" is the schema. If you create them with the wrong schema, it will not work, because, as you can see, "public" is  hard coded string read at runtime at the "migration generate time". Only solution I can think of would be to create the migrations with the schema from api call and then run them. So: generate + run migrations instead of only run migrations via api call

Comment: they do look something similar, but, instead of altering tables, my  migrations are responsible for creating tables, and I was looking to avoid the name prefix as much as possible, I also tried setting search paths, but, that also required manual queries concatenated on the actual table creation code. Having manual tinkering is a bit of maintainence hassle I think

Comment: If it is just for creating tables, I would go with the `synchronize: true` flag even people tend to say that it's  better to avoid that in production environments.

Comment: yeah, I mean, its horrible in production, but, that does work for development, and should had been a trigger for production, don't know why there isn't. Writing entities and then maintaining separate migration files doesn't really make sense to me