# does set search_path of postgres affect connection or the database

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Typeorm's migration is quite unexpected, [even though I specify the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73301923/how-to-migrate-schema-specific-in-typeorm/73302246?noredirect=1#comment129456956_73302246), migrations run though the `queryRunner`, don't respect the `schema` specified in the connection:

```
const dbconfig: DataSourceOptions = {
      ...baseConnection,
      schema: my_schema,
      migrations: ['./**/*.migration.js'],
    };

let data = new DataSource(dbconfig);
data = await data.initialize();
data.runMigrations()
```

it only seems to work if you've used something like a repository, orm specific.

One way I got around this is by using a static variable that persists throughout the migration process the name of the schema, and sets search_path of the database before each query, like this:

```
    set search_path to ${static_variable.my_schema};
    run_query_1;

    set search_path to ${static_variable.my_schema};
    run_query_2;
    ...

    set search_path to ${static_variable.my_schema};
    run_query_n;
```

Consider this case,(1) an admin starts a migration, the schema is set to 'X', the database search_path is set to 'X', in the midst of this process, if a request comes in from tenant 'Y', then would he be writing to the tenant 'X' or 'Y'

(2) If the app is horizontally scaled, then if two admins are performing migrations for two tenants, (there are two different static vars now), how would this affect the authenticity and integrity of the data.

If the `set search_path` is connection specifically maintained, then I suppose it could matter less , but if the database globally manages it, this could be an issue.

Are these concurrent operations going to be a problem? Should I opt to modify the search_path at all?

EDIT: What about for the case like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    set search_path to ${static_variable.my_schema};
    run_query_1;

    set search_path to ${static_variable.my_schema};
    run_query_2;
    ...

    set search_path to ${static_variable.my_schema};
    run_query_n;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) `SET` changes the setting for the session (or just the transaction if the `local` keyword is included).

So if you always use `set search_patt to ...` it's always specific to the connection (session) that executed the statement. You will not have a concurrency issue.

There is one way this could have an effect globally: if you change the search path in the database using `alter database set search_path ...` or for the user using `alter user set search_path ...`

Comment: is there a command to terminate the session from postgres after the end of the transaction? I'm wondering if the sessions are pooled or not for the connection to be reused?

Comment: also the doc says: `SET LOCAL last only till the end of the current transaction` , can the same session be used for multiple transactions concurrently? Or a new transaction will have to use a new or unused session?

Comment: what about for the case if wrapped by an outer transaction, as I have updated in the question above.